# shared preference reading values returns defaultvalues

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I think I'm missing something in retrieving values from `SharedPreferences`.

My code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView password;
    private EditText username;
    private Button button;
    private String name;
    private String pass;
    private Set<String> set;
    private TextView show;
    SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        myPrefs = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = myPrefs.edit();

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        name = username.getText().toString();
        pass = password.getText().toString();

        /*
         * set = new HashSet<String>(); set.add(name); set.add(pass);
         */

    }

    public void saveToPreference(View v) {

        editor.putString("UserName", name);
        editor.putString("Password", pass);
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String use = myPref.getString("UserName", "Sorry");
        String pas = myPref.getString("Password", "SorryAgain");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), use, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        show.append(use + "\n" + pas);

    }

}
```

App doesn't force/close. Instead I am getting defaultValues; "Sorry","SorryAgain" are retrieved from `SharedPreferences`. `"Sorry"` gets toasted.

What else should I do?

Comment: LogCat shows, at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)   at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42), illegal state exception, etc...

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace? Also, as a first observation: if you're reading from `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());` then you should be writing in the same `SharedPreferences` store.

Comment: Tried that but now empty string is returned...

Comment: User user1455909 (below) has provided the correct answer. You are doing 2 wrong things: 1. Writing and reading in different preferences. 2. In onCreate you're getting the text from username and password, store those and then save in button click. Get the values in button click, not in onCreate.

Comment: Ya now i got the mistake. Thanks a lot gunar and userxxx....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the `preferences` returned by:

```
this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then you are reading the preferences returned by:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

You should initialise myPrefs in `onCreate` and then use that instance in all the `Activity` functions to ensure you are using exactly the same `SharedPreferences`. Something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

     myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     editor = myPrefs.edit();


     username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

}   


    public void saveToPreference(View v){

    editor.putString("UserName",username.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("Password", password.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    String use = myPrefs.getString("UserName", "Sorry");
    String pas = myPrefs.getString("Password", "SorryAgain");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), use,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    show.append(use+"\n"+ pas);


}
```

Comment: changed the code as you mentioned. Now nothing is toasted. Not even the default value. Logcat shows nothing

Comment: Just the empty string value is returned

Comment: The variables name and pass aren't empty when you use putString?

Comment: I modified the code above. You were checking EditTexts contents in onCreate, and usually those values are empty when the Activity is created. You should retrieve their contents in saveToPreference function, like I do in the code above. Try it and let me know if it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//In oncreate if its an activity or do it on top of class
    SharedPreferences myPref= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

//Add data after getting it from edittext
    editor.putString("UserName",name);
     editor.putString("Password", pass);
     editor.commit();

//get data
     String use = myPref.getString("UserName", "Sorry");
     String pas = myPref.getString("Password", "SorryAgain");
```

Comment: Happy to help :-) support upvoting